# show that $H\cap Z(P)>\{1_{G}\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I working on exrcise that state:

> Let G be a group, and subgroups $P,H\leq G$.
> Also, P is a p-subgroup(prime p), H abelian, $H\trianglelefteq G$.
> Assume, $H\cap P >\{1_{G}\}$.
> Show that $H\cap Z(P)>\{1_{G}\}$.
> (H need not be abelian for this to hold)

My attempt so far:

**In case P=G:**

$|H|=p^t$ for $t\in \mathbb {N}$, H is a union of adjacency classes of G.

Let $x_{1}=1_{G},x_{2},...,x_{m}$ different representatives of all the adjacency classes in H, so the first n apply $|[x_{i}]|=1$.

so, $|H|=\sum_{i=1}^{n}[x_{i}]+\sum_{i=n+1}^{m}[x_{i}]$.

Because $p||H|$, $p|\sum_{i=n+1}^{m}[x_{i}]$ $\Longrightarrow n\geq p$.

Therefore, there is $[x_{i}]=1$, so $C(x_{i})=G$.

**In case $P\neq G$:**

So, ${1_{G}}<H\cap P<G$

Let $1_{G}\neq x\in H\cap P >\{1_{G}\}$, so $x\in H \wedge x\in P$.

- I know there is non-trivial $p\in P$ such that $C(a)=P$
- Because H is abelian for all $h\in H$ $x^h=x$

I can't find how to get that for $p\in P$ $x^p=x$.

Comment: 1) $H$ need not be abelian for this to hold. 2) Do the case $P=G$ first.

Comment: The case $P\neq G$ is trivial, once $P=G$ is done. Reduce one to the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that all this is superfluous.

Hints.

Since $K=H\cap P$ is normal subgroup of group $P$ and $K\neq\{1\}$, then $K=\cup C_i$, where $C_i$ is conjugacy class in group $P$. It follows that $|K|=\sum|C_i|$ and $p^r=1+\sum p^{r_i}$. So there is at least one more conjugacy class consisting of a single element.

Comment: How do you know the subgroup K is normal?

Comment: By the condition $H\lhd G$, so $H\cap P\lhd P$. This follows from the definition of a normal subgroup.